# what is the difference between 観察 and 観測

Tags: word-choice

According to JDIC, both mean "observation".
Judging from the Kanji used, I'm guessing the difference is 観測 has a nuance of observing something and measuring some aspect of it or taking data, whereas 観察 is just to observe and monitor what's happening.

Comment: This might help too: https://hinative.com/ja/questions/943135

Answer (score 4):

You guess is right. And 観測 can also mean prediction based on the data observed (e.g. 希望的観測).

Some details can be found is the explanation of the two word: [観察](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/14519/m0u/%E8%A6%B3%E5%AF%9F/) [観測](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/14840/m0u/%E8%A6%B3%E6%B8%AC/)